# Where do I find drivers for the SideTrack monitor?

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

I used the Sidetrack monitor for six weeks running Ubuntu 20.04 after installing drivers and running an application.   I reinstalled the operating system,  but lost the drivers, the application and the location where I obtained them.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the driver from DisplayLink: https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu
2. Extract the driver from your Downloads folder.
3. Open a terminal in the extracted file path and run the install script:

sudo ./displaylink-driver-XXXX.run
Note that the actual .run will vary based on the version you downloaded. Power user tip here: type out "sudo ./displ" and hit tab to allow the command line to autocomplete the driver for you. I often use this to avoid mistyping a file.

https://engineerworkshop.com/blog/adding-a-portable-usb-monitor-to-ubuntu-how-to-set-up-a-displaylink-driver/